# Probability question about virus testing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I got the following homework assignment and I am having a hard time solving the second question. It goes like this:

1000 people come to test for a virus, the probability that one person have the virus is $p$ in an independent way. We divide the people to 50 equal groups, $A_{1},\ldots,A_{50}$ in the first stage we mix the sample of the people in some group and checks if the virus is in the mixed sample, and afterwards, for every group which has the virus we check the people individually for the virus.

1. by using $p$ shows what the expected value of the number of tests the lab has to make.
2. Assume the group testing are random, and after wards we make the individual's test also in a random way(random between all the people from all the positive groups). If Z is a random variable indicating how many tests passed until we know if anna's(random person) test is negative\positive. Show the expected value of Z using $p$.

My solution for 1 was $E\left(X\right)=50\cdot\left(21-20\left(1-p\right)^{20}\right)$, I used $X_{1},\ldots,X_{50}$ to compute the expected value of testing in each group, which came out as $$E\left(X_{i}\right)=1\cdot P\left(P_{1}=0,\ldots,P_{20}=0\right)+21\cdot P\left(\text{at least one is sick}\right)=21-20\left(1-p\right)^{20}$$ $$E\left(X\right)=50\cdot E\left(X_{i}\right)=50\left(21-20\left(1-p\right)^{20}\right)$$Is it right?

And for 2 I wanted to use $Y\sim\text{Ber}\left(1-\left(1-p\right)^{20}\right)$, random variable indicating whether anna's group tested positive or not, my idea is to compute $E\left(E\left[Z|Y\right]\right)=E\left(Z\right)$ it came out that $E\left(Z|Y=0\right)=25.5$ but I am having a hard time solving $E\left(Z|Y=1\right)$ as it starts to became real ugly, is it the right way? or am I just not using the right method to solve it? any help is welcomed, thank you!

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear. For the first procedure:  For each group, of $20$ individuals, we run a mass test to determine if at least one person in the group has the virus and if the answer is yes we then run $20$ individual tests in that group?  Right?  And I can't sort out the second procedure at all.

Comment: If my interpretation of the first procedure is correct, then I agree with your expected value.  For a different argument, just work group by group.  We conduct exactly $1$ test with probability $(1-p)^{20}$ and we conduct $21$ tests with probability $(1-(1-p)^{20})$.  Now just read off the expected number and multiply by $50$.

Comment: @lulu Sorry for not being clear, you assumed right in the first procedure. In the next one we do the same, mass test to determine if a group has the virus(counts as 1 test), we do it on all the groups in a random order. afterwards, we take all the people from the positive groups and checks them randomly(doesn't matter what group they were in). and we want to find the expected value of how many test we made until we got to the test of some random person, this case we call her anna.

Again, sorry for my English, I hope I am more clear now.

Comment: Ok, so you should condition the computation on whether or not person $A$ is in an infected group or not, and (if they are) condition further on how many infected groups there are.  I assume that while we are testing randomly (either groups or individuals) we keep track of those we have tested so nobody gets tested more than once, right?

Comment: On reflection, I'd first separate into cases according to whether or not $A$ is personally infected, and then condition on the number of infected groups.

Comment: @lulu in the mass testing, they don't test them individually, they mix the samples and check if the group has the virus. only then they will check if an individual has the virus.

I tried as you proposed first, to condition whether or not person A is in infected group or not. but when conditioning on how many infected groups there are, things got messy, let's say number of infected groups (except A's group) is Y so we get that $$P(Y=k)={49 \choose k}\left(1-\left(1-p\right)^{20}\right)^{k}\cdot\left(\left(1-p\right)^{20}\right)^{49-k}$$, and trying computing the expected value got messy.

Comment: Again, conditioned on whether or not $A's$ group is infected or not, you could convince yourself that you only need the expected number of infected groups.  (N.B. I *think* that's true but I'd probably do the full computation, on a machine of course, to be sure).

Comment: @lulu I am having hard time computing it this way, I am probably missing something. If we say Z is number of tests till we got to A(assuming A's group is positive and not including the groups tests) I get: $$E\left(Z'\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{49}E\left(Z'|A=i\right)P\left(A=i\right)$$ and $$E\left(Z'|A=i\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{20+i\cdot20}i\cdot P\left(Z'=j|A=i\right)$$ which equals $11.5+10i$ so I stuck with $$\sum_{i=0}^{49}\left(11.5+10i\right){49 \choose i}\left(1-\left(1-p\right)^{20}\right)^{i}\cdot\left(\left(1-p\right)^{20}\right)^{49-i}$$ in the first equation.

Comment: I just automated the computation.  Perhaps the sum has a sensible expression, perhaps not...but it's an easy machine computation (for any given $p$).  If I am correct that you only need the expected number (and I am pretty sure I am) then you can get a closed formula similar to the one you got in part $(1)$.

Comment: @lulu yeah, that's for sure, I just assumed there is a way to get a sensible expression, that's why I asked the question in the first place.

How would you use the expected number?

Comment: So, again, persuade yourself that you can just assume the expected number of infected groups (conditioned on the status of $A$ and $A's$ group).  Then, having broken into cases where $A$ either is or is not personally infected, the computation is a simple sum.

Comment: But, really, you should automate the direct computation first, regardless.  That way you'll be able to test whatever simplified expression you arrive at.  This sort of thing can be fairly error prone.